# Iterate over Umbraco getAllTagsInGroup result

Tags: xpath, umbraco, asp.net-3.5, umbraco-tags

I'm trying to get a list of tags from a particular tag group in Umbraco (v4.0.2.1) using the following code:

```
var tags = umbraco.editorControls.tags.library.getAllTagsInGroup("document downloads");
```

What I want to do is just output a list of those tags.  However, if I output the variable 'tags' it just outputs a list of all tags in a string.  I want to split each tag onto a new line.

When I check the datatype of the 'tags' variable:

```
string tagType = tags.GetType().ToString();
```

...it outputs `MS.Internal.Xml.XPath.XPathSelectionIterator`.

So question is, how do I get the individual tags out of the 'tags' variable?  How do I work with a variable of this data type?  I can find examples of how to do it by loading an actual XML file, but I don't have an actual XML file - just the 'tags' variable to work with.

Thanks very much for any help!

**EDIT1**: I guess what I'm asking is, how do I loop through the nodes returned by an XPathSelectionIterator data type?

**EDIT2**: I've found this code, which almost does what I need:

```
        XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("file.xml");
        XPathNavigator navigator = document.CreateNavigator();

        XPathNodeIterator nodes = navigator.Select("/tags/tag");
        nodes.MoveNext();
        XPathNavigator nodesNavigator = nodes.Current;

        XPathNodeIterator nodesText = nodesNavigator.SelectDescendants(XPathNodeType.Text, false);

        while (nodesText.MoveNext())
            debugString += nodesText.Current.Value.ToString();
```

...but it expects the URL of an actual XML file to load into the first line.  My XML file is essentially the 'tags' variable, not an actual XML file.  So when I replace:

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument("file.xml");
```

...with:

```
XPathDocument document = new XPathDocument(tags);
```

...it just errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is an Iterator, I would suggest you iterate it. ;-)

```
var tags = umbraco.editorControls.tags.library.getAllTagsInGroup("document downloads");

foreach (XPathNavigator tag in tags) {
  // handle current tag
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tomalak.  I've tried the following:

   var tags = umbraco.editorControls.tags.library.getAllTagsInGroup("document downloads");
   foreach (XPathNavigator tag in tags)
   {
    debugString += tag.ToString() + " <br /> ";

   }


But it just outputs all tags as a single string - it doesn't seem to iterate through each one as it should.

Comment: Although I can't find any way of actually outputting the full XML code for the 'tags' variable, I've found the documentation on the 'getAllTagsInGroup' method, which says that it "returns the found nodes as: <tags><tag id="" nodesTagged="" group="">tagname<tag> etc...</tags>".  So presumably I need some way to tell it to iterate through just the 'tag' nodes?  I think currently it must be returning the full 'tags' node rather than each tag node individually.

Comment: @Dan: You already found a way to select certain descendant nodes. All you need to do is spend a little time in the debugger and apply that knowledge to the situation. ;-)

Comment: I'm a complete ASP.NET novice though Tomalak. This is my issue. What I've got here is way beyond the boundaries of my understanding of ASP.NET, but I've pieced it together over a couple of days of Googling and simple trial and error. There comes a point though when I need to ask for help, and that point is where I'm at. This is for a commercial project so I can't afford to spend another 2 days scratching my head and going in circles. I really do try to do my own research and come up with my own solutions, but like I say, I'm well out of my depth here and would really appreciate the assistance.

Comment: From a practical point of view, the particular difficulty I'm finding right now is that I don't have a variable of XPathNavigator data type, so I have nothing to apply the ".Select('tags/tag')" to.  I've tried casting, and converting various things, but to no avail.

Comment: @Dan: If `getAllTagsInGroup()` really returns the equivalent of `<tags><tag>…</tag><tag>…</tag></tags>`, then calling `Current()` on it returns the `XPathNavigator` for the `<tags>` node. And this object exposes a `Select()` method that accepts XPath and returns a `XPathNodeIterator` you can use with `foreach`. I can't say for sure though since I have no experience with Umbraco.

Comment: Thanks.  When I call getAllTagsInGroup() though it returns a data type of XPathNodeIterator.  If I try to add .Current() to the end of that, it errors, saying "Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathNodeIterator' to 'System.Xml.XPath.XPathNavigator'".  Any ideas?

Comment: Got it!  I was doing .Current() when I should have been doing just .Current without parentheses!  Thanks Tomalak, you have steered me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does the trick a little better.

The problem is that getAllTagsInGroup returns the container for all tags, you need to get its children.

```
foreach( var tag in umbraco.editorControls.tags.library.getAllTagsInGroup("category").Current.Select("/tags/tag") )
{
     /// Your Code
}
```